# How do I make a touch system based on pixels touching each other?

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I'm working on a game engine and I want to make its touch system just a block of a hit box, especially considering I don't know how to make the hit box rotate. I don't want the hit box to be invisible spaces being touched and then it runs a function, because if it does then that wouldn't be a good thing with the engine because people would think they didn't even touch it. Can someone give me scripts to be able to do this?
This is what I have for the positions so far.

```js
const console = { log: function(value) { logs.innerHTML = logs.innerHTML + "<br/>" + value; }, clear: logs.innerHTML = "" };
const logs = document.getElementById("console");
const e = window.event;
var triggerBox = [];
var entities = [];
const last = { keyPressed: e.keyCode, boxTriggerer:"" };
const bind = {keys:{ one: '49', two: '50', three: '51', four: '52', five: '53', six: '54', seven: '55', eight: '56', nine: '58', zero: '48', tab: '9', shift: '16', ctrl: '17', alt: '18', enter: '13', backSpace: '8', esc: '27', optionMenu: '91', space: '32', leftArrow: '37', downArrow: '40', upArrow: '38', rightArrow: '39', q: '81', w: '87', e: '69', r: '82', t: '84', y: '89', u: '85', i: '73', o: '79', p: '80', a: '65', s: '83', d: '68', f: '70', g: '71', h: '72', j: '74', k: '75', l: '76', z: '90', x: '88', c: '67', v: '86', b: '66', n: '78', m: '77'}};
function Destroy(name) {
  var destroywhat = document.getElementByClassName(name);
  destroywhat.parentNode.removeChild(destroywhat);
}
const game = document.getElementById('project');
const create = { entity: function(Type, Width, Height, posX, posY, Rot, Image) { document.getElementById("project").innerHTML = `${document.getElementById("project").innerHTML} <img src='${Image}' width='${Width}' height='${Height}' id='${Type}' class='ragolationUnit' style='position:absolute;left:${posX};bottom:${posY};rotate(${Rot});'/>` }, };

function X(name) {
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
      return entities[c].x;
    }
  }
}

function Y(name) {
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
      return entities[c].y;
    }
  }
}

function changeX(name,amount) {
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
      entities[c].x = entities[c].x + amount;
    }
  }
}

function changeY(name,amount) {
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
      entities[c].y = entities[c].y + amount;
    }
  }
}

function Width(name){
    for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
      return entities[c].width;
    }
  }
}

function changeWidth(name,amount){
    for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
     entities[c].width = entities[c].width + amount;
    }
  }
}

function Height(name){
    for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
      return entities[c].height;
    }
  }
}

function changeHeight(name,amount){
    for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
     entities[c].height = entities[c].height + amount;
    }
  }
}

function percentage(min,amount,max){
  return (max / (100 + min)) * amount;
}

function randomNumber(min,max){
  return (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function createTriggerBox(name,x,y,width,height){
  triggerBox.push({title:name, posX:x, posY:y, minX:x - (width / 2), maxX:x + (width / 2), minY:y - (height / 2), maxY:y + (height / 2), enabled:true});
}
function TriggeredBox(name,action){
  for(let c = 0; c == triggerBox.length; c++){
    if(triggerBox[c].name == name){
      if(document.querySelector('.entity').style.left > triggerBox[c].minX){
        if(document.querySelector('.entity').style.left < triggerBox[c].maxX){
          if(document.querySelector('.entity').style.bottom > triggerBox[c].minY){          
            if(document.querySelector('.entity').style.bottom < triggerBox[c].maxY){
              if(triggerBox[c].enabled == true){
                last.boxTriggerer = document.querySelector('.entity').id;
                setTimeout(action,40);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function enableTriggerBox(name,bool){
  for(let c = 0; triggerBox[c].title == name; c++){
    if(triggerBox[c].title == name){
      if(bool == true || bool == false){
        triggerBox[c].enabled = bool;
      }
    }
  }
}
  function midPos(pointA,pointB,pointC,pointD,goal){
    var mathA;
    var mathB;
    if(pointA > 0){
      mathA = pointC + pointA;
    }else{
      mathA = pointC - pointA;
    }
    if(pointB > 0){
      mathB = pointD + pointB;
    }else{
      mathB = pointD - pointB;
    }
    mathA = mathA / 2;
    mathB = mathB / 2;
    if(goal.toLowerCase() == "y"){
      return mathB;
    }
    if(goal.toLowerCase() == "x"){
      return mathA;
    }
  }
  function endPos(pointA,pointB,pointC,pointD,goal){
    var mathA;
    var mathB;
    if(pointA > 0){
      mathA = pointC - pointA;
    }else{
      mathA = pointC + pointA;
    }
    if(pointB > 0){
      mathB = pointD - pointB;
    }else{
      mathB = pointD + pointB;
    }
    if(goal.toLowerCase() == "y"){
      return pointD + mathB;
    }
    if(goal.toLowerCase() == "x"){
      return pointC + mathA;
    }
  }
  function getSlope(pointA,pointB,pointC,pointD){
    return (pointB - pointD) / (pointA - pointC);
  }
  function getDistance(pointA,pointB,pointC,pointD){
    return Math.round(Math.sqrt(((pointC - PointA) * (pointC - PointA)) + ((pointD - PointB) * (pointD - PointB)));
  }
  function createTrigger(){
    
  }
  function whenTrigger(){
    
  }
  function repeat(def,val){
    for(let r = 0; r < val; r++){
      setTimeout(def,10);
    }
  }
function repeatForever(def){
  while(true){
    setTimeout(def,10);
  }
}
function moveForward(name,times){
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
     entities[c].x = entities[c].x + Math.cos(entities[c].rotDeg);
     entities[c].y = entities[c].y + Math.sin(entities[c].rotDeg);
    }
  }
}
function moveBackward(name,times){
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
     entities[c].x = entities[c].x + Math.cos(entities[c].rotDeg - 180);
     entities[c].y = entities[c].y + Math.sin(entities[c].rotDeg - 180);
    }
  }
}
function moveRight(name, times){
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
     entities[c].x = entities[c].x + Math.cos(entities[c].rotDeg + 90);
     entities[c].y = entities[c].y + Math.sin(entities[c].rotDeg + 90);
    }
  }  
}
function moveLeft(name, times){
  for(let c = 0; entities[c].name == name; c++){
    if(entities[c].name == name){
     entities[c].x = entities[c].x + Math.cos(entities[c].rotDeg - 90);
     entities[c].y = entities[c].y + Math.sin(entities[c].rotDeg - 90);
    }
  }  
}
  document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState !== "complete") {
      
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#loader").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
};
while(true){
    for(let c = 0; c == entities.length; c++){
      document.getElementById(entities[c].name).style.left = `${(window.screen.width / 2) + entities[c].x}`;
      document.getElementById(entities[c].name).style.bottom = `${(window.screen.height / 2) + entities[c].y}`;
      document.getElementById(entities[c].name).style.width = entities[c].width;
      document.getElementById(entities[c].name).style.height = entities[c].height;
      document.getElementById(entities[c].name).style.transform = `${entities[c].rotDeg}deg`;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Is the game engine based on HTML elements? It should be made on HTML canvas instead, and/or the entities should be stored as objects

Comment: it indeed is based on HTML elements.

Comment: You won't make it far with HTML elements only. Try to make a class with values as the widths, heights and rotations and find out how to draw everything on a canvas. Once you get the hang of it, you will find it a lot easier.

Comment: @Ath.Bar. I want it to be a full HTML elements game engine though

Comment: you can still make the classes as said, with the computations being done in javascript, and only output the position to your elements. But you for sure have to make the engine in JavaScript both for speed and for your own convenience

Comment: @Ath.Bar. what about the touching pixel thing though

Comment: That's the point. Personally I can't help you with that. As HTML elements the objects are only rendered as rotated but not really thought of this way. you still get the initial bounds from the classic methods. That means unless you do a really hacky way involving a lot of math too you can't really make it perfect and I can't help you